# How can I get Xcode to Compile my code instead of doing Build AST?

Tags: xcode, clang

I just converted a Framework project from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4. I've been building this project for years under every version of Xcode and Project Builder.

For some reason, Xcode 4 runs Build AST on all of my classes rather than Compile, which doesn't actually build the framework executable. On digging into it I found that this passes the -fsyntax-only flag to clang which tells it to stop after producing an Abstract Syntax Tree for each class. I have another Framework that builds fine in Xcode 4, and I've compared the build settings without uncovering anything that looks like it would cause this.

Does anyone have an idea what would make Xcode want to perform the Build AST action rather than Compile? And more to the point, how to turn that behavior off?

Thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found that in my case I had a custom Build Rule for '*.i' files in my project. The clang build process apparently produces .i files (along with several others) as an intermediate product, so this rule was interfering and stopping it from completing all stages of the build. Removing the custom Build Rule allowed everything to build normally.